# mysql get recordset of latest rows depend on other column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some columns, between them there are 2 columns: equipment_id (a String) and date_saved (a DateTime field).
I have multiple rows with the same equipment_id and but different date_saved (each time the user saves the record I save the now date time).
I want to retrieve a list of records that the equipment_id starts with a string (which can be empty) and is the latest saved, i.e.:

| Equipment_id | Date_saved |
| --- | --- |
| 1061a | 26-DEC-2020 10:10:23 |
| 1061a | 26-DEC-2020 10:11:52 |
| 1061a | 26-DEC-2020 10:22:03 |
| 1061a | 26-DEC-2020 10:31:15 |
| 1062a | 21-DEC-2020 10:11:52 |
| 1062a | 25-DEC-2020 10:22:03 |
| 1073a | 20-DEC-2020 10:31:15 |

Output:

```
| 1061a   | 26-DEC-2020 10:31:15|   
| 1062a   | 25-DEC-2020 10:22:03|  
| 1073a   | 20-DEC-2020 10:31:15|
```

I have tried various approach without success:

```
 select * from program_program 
 where date_saved=(select MAX(program_program.date_saved) 
                   from program_program)
```

I only get the latest record, not the list of records I wanted

Comment: The subquery isn't required if you want `MAX(saved_date)` by `Equipment_id`.

Comment: I did the subquery when I was trying to refine the query for the equipment_id like % without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the latest Date_saved by Equipment_id, possible restricted by a Equipment_id:

```
select Equipment_id, max(Date_saved) as 'Date_saved'
from program_program
where Equipment_id like '%'
group by 1;
```

The only tricky thing is that none of the other columns of program_program are well defined, so you need to join with program_program to get at this:

```
select p.*
from program_program p
natural join (
  select Equipment_id, max(Date_saved) as 'Date_saved'
  from program_program
  where Equipment_id like '%'
  group by 1 
) p2;
```

Comment: I need the first part of your answer but with all columns retrieved not just equipment_id and date_saved

Comment: That is why I gave you the 2nd query my friend :-)

Comment: Many thanks, the result wasn't ok because I had bad data